# Clustering algorithm for specificing n points per cluster?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a clustering algorithm where you set a number of points, which the algorithm would aim for in the clusters. For example, if I have 10 total data points, n=5, the algorithm would then cluster and group them into 2 clusters. If it total was 11 and n=5, it would group 2 clusters, one with 5 and one with 6.

I was thinking I could use agglomerative clustering and then stop at a certain number of clusters but I was wondering if this is the wrong approach, and I shouldn't be doing clustering at all and using something else to group items? Thanks.

Comment: K means.   See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html

Comment: K means defines the number of clusters, I want to define the number of points per cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, clustering methodologies are unsupervised, so you don't train/test anything. You let the algo tell you the story, based on the data that is fed in. You don't know what will happen in advance. In short, with DBSCAN and also Hierarchical Clustering (but not K-Means), you do not pre-specify the number of clusters. The algo determines the optimal number of clusters for you. If you really want to control the number of clusters (min or max) you need to use a K-Means algo. Take a look at this link when you have a chance.

https://blog.cambridgespark.com/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-for-k-means-clustering-14f27070048f